# В Visual Code Studio не работают обратные кавычки

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, кавычки

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: часть кода, заключённая в обратные кавычки в Visual Studio Code, как будто бы исчезает, то есть даже палитра синтаксиса выделяет эту часть не как обычный код, а как строку.

```
if (block.type === 'title') {
        html = `
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <h1>${block.value}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        `
    }
```

Не понимаю, грамматически ведь всё правильно? Возможно, что-то не хватает моему VSC? Но я прошерстила все возможные плагины, ни в одном не нашла особенного пункта про обратные кавычки.

Буду очень-очень признательна за помощь!

Comment: Все правильно, в обратных кавычках - строка. Только вот строка далее может быть распарсена как HTML разметка. Обратные кавычки позволяют вставлять значения из переменных при помощи синтаксиса `text ${} text` вместо `"text " + variable + " text"`

Comment: В JS не будет подкрашиваться HTML, по крайней мере VSCode так не умеет. А так, это строковая интерполяция, обратные кавычки формируют шаблонные строки, поэтому и текст будет подсвечиваться как строка, кроме выражений, вставленных через `${}`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Интерполяция! Лучше изучила данную тему, спасибо большое за комментарий и помощь!